# Is Safari 9.0.2 support for data URI broken?

Tags: url, safari, base64, data-uri

I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ciaoben/g8rt638v/),
but can't make ti work in safari. In every other browser it works without flaws. I have read that safari supports data URI, so , I am missing something? Or is a bug?

I am using a simple

```
<img src="...">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, data in this manner cannot have line breaks, and it appears that your fiddle has them. I would recommend trying this without any line breaks, white-space, etc. I'm not sure why that would differ in Safari, but who knows.